# Most efficient way to parse through nested dictionaries

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following dictionary:

```
var masterDict = [Double : [Date:[String:Any]]]()
```

I would like to retrieve the following information based on this data source:

- The earliest `Date` object to exist in the dictionary (search all `Double` keys).
- The latest/furthest `Date` object to exist in the dictionary (search all `Double` keys).

My thoughts are to loop through the `.keys` of the `Dictionary` and then enumerate that way, but I am asking if there is a Swiftier way to accomplish retrieving this information (possibly faster too)?

Comment: What do you mean by the latest date?  masterDict is a dictionary, not an array of dictionary.

Comment: So for every key that exists in masterDict, there is another dictionary with a Date set as the key for that dictionary. I am asking to essentially evaluate every key of masterDict, get the secondary Date key of the corresponding nested dictionary, and evaluate out of all those retrieved dates which is the earliest and which is the date that is furthest in the future (latest date).

Comment: Can you please provide some data to test?

Comment: I have uploaded demo data here: https://pastebin.com/MF45XJ8u

Comment: Can you please try out my solution ?

Comment: It works, but how to get let latestDate = (sorted.first?.value.keys.last)! as you cannot call .last on .keys.

Comment: @user13138159 to get the latest date you just need use `sorted.last?.value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all get the all the `values` from `masterDict` and flatten them out using **`flatMap(_:)`** create a single `Array`,

```
let values = masterDict.values.flatMap { $0 }
```

Next, sort the `values` in *ascending order* using **`sorted(_:)`**

```
let sortedValues = values.sorted { $0.key.compare($1.key) == .orderedAscending }
```

Now use `first` and `last` on the `sortedValues` to get the latest and further `Date` instance,

```
let first = sortedValues.first?.key
let last = sortedValues.last?.key
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sort function on dictionary, sort condition will be based on dates comparison.

```
var masterDict = [Double : [Date:[String:Any]]]()
```

You can access latest and furthest date based on it.

```
let sorted = masterDict.sorted { (dict1, dict2) -> Bool in
    return dict1.value.keys.first! < dict2.value.keys.first!
}
```

Try first and last properties on sorted array of dictionary to get the latest date.

```
print(sorted.first!.value)
print(sorted.last!.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to extract all dates values

```
let allDates = masterDict.reduce(into: []) { $0.append(contentsOf: $1.value.keys) }
```

and then you can simply get the min and max dates

```
print(allDates.max())
print(allDates.min())
```

or if you prefer first and last you can sort the array

```
let allDates = masterDict.reduce(into: []) { $0.append(contentsOf: $1.value.keys) }.sorted()

print(allDates.last)
print(allDates.first)
```